# Redirect to current URL while changing a query parameter in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is there a built-in way to do something like this?

Let's say I have a search-page that has a few parameters in the URL:

```
example.com/search?term=foo&type=user
```

A link on that page would redirect to an URL where `type` is `link`. I'm looking for a method to do this without manually constructing the URL.

**Edit:**
I could build the URL manually like so:

```
$qs = http_build_query(array(
    'term' => Input::get('term'),
    'type' => Input::get('type')
));
$url = URL::to('search?'.$qs);
```

However, what I wanted to know is if there is a nicer, built-in way of doing this in Laravel, because the code gets messier when I want to change one of those values.

Giving the URL generator a second argument (`$parameters`) adds them to the URL as segments, not in the query string.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the URL Generator to accomplish this.  Assuming that search is a named route:

```
$queryToAdd = array('type' => 'user');
$currentQuery = Input::query();

// Merge our new query parameters into the current query string
$query = array_merge($queryToAdd, $currentQuery);

// Redirect to our route with the new query string
return Redirect::route('search', $query);
```

Laravel will take the positional parameters out of the passed array (which doesn't seem to apply to this scenario), and append the rest as a query string to the generated URL.

See: [`URLGenerator::route()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.1.21/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L186-L211),
[`URLGenerator::replaceRouteParameters()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.1.21/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L246-L263)
[`URLGenerator::getRouteQueryString()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.1.21/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L281-L309)

Comment: Does it append them to query string only when using a named route? `URL::to()` adds them to the URL as segments. See my edit.

Comment: @MarttiLaine - It doesn't seem to using `::to()`.  I'm not really sure that, structurally, I'd recommend that.  Is there some reason why you can't use `URL::action('MyController@search')`?

Comment: @MarttiLaine using Url::route() as I suggested will add the second parameter to the query string

Answer (score 7):

I prefer native PHP array merging to override some parameters:

```
['type' => 'link'] + \Request::all()
```

To add or override the `type` parameter and remove another the `term`:

```
['type' => 'link'] + \Request::except('term')
```

Usage when generating routes:

```
route('movie::category.show', ['type' => 'link'] + \Request::all())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [Laravel's URLGenerator](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php)

```
URL::route('search', array(
  'term' => Input::get('term'),
  'link' => Input::get('type')
));
```

Edit: be sure to name the route in your routes.php file:

```
Route::get('search', array('as' => 'search'));
```

That will work even if you're using a Route::controller()

Answer (score 1):

From [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects#redirecting-named-routes):

> if your route has parameters, you may pass them as the second argument
>   to the route method.

In this case, for return an URI like ***example.com/search?term=foo&type=user***, you can use redirect function like this:

```
return redirect()->route('search', ['term' => 'foo', 'type' => 'user']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a built in way. You can do your manipulation in [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#defining-middleware).

The `$request` passed to the handle method of all middleware has a `query` property. As an [InputBag](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-httpfoundation-improvements#added-inputbag), it comes with a few methods; Namely, for your intentions: `->set()`.

Pretty self explanatory, but here's an example:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $request->query->set('term','new-value');

    // now you pass the request (with the manipulated query) down the pipeline.
    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The Input component should also contain query parameters.

i.e `Input::get('foo');`